# GPS data -tracking analyst

Tags: arcgis-desktop, carto, gps, google-earth, tracking

i have GPS data from 15 trucks for one month. The data include (location x-y, speed, altitude and vehicle_id). I have used tracking analyst to visualize the data but i need to group them by day to show each truck's trip in detail. Because not all the cars travel every day and same hours.. So i get no result if i put them altogether.

How can i check that my GPS data has no bias?

i observed that there are cases when a truck makes a trip from a to b it turns off the gps at b and the other day it starts again from a. So when i get ArcGIS to calculate distances it appears a wrong (and often too big) distance.

How can i fix that? Should i split my dataset by day?

Comment: Please take the [Tour] where you will see that there should only be one question per question.

Comment: How can i check my GPS data for bias?

Comment: There is an **edit** button beneath your question which will enable you to remove the additional one to focus on this one and to provide more details about it.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that depending on the software that you use to do the sum, if one vehicle has no data, then the final sum is invalid.
As a simple workaround, you can set value to 0 (zero) for those cars/trucks without data and then do the sum.
This workaround is not helpful if you want to know which car did not travel on a specific date.